# How to only export specific methods from a class?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a class which has 10 methods, and only 8 of those 10 should be exported, the other 2 are for authenticating tokens and I don't want them to be exported since the user won't need to call them ever ( I'm writing a package for npmjs ), my question is, how to only export the class with those 8 methods while the class itself is using the other two?

Edit: added some code

```js
class StackClass {
  constructor(p1, p2) {
    this.data = {
      p1,
      p2,
      accessToken: null,
      expiresIn: null,
      tokenType: null
    };
  }

  async getToken() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        let fetchResponse = await fetch(
          "url with this.data.p1 and this.data.p2"
        );
        let fetchData = await fetchResponse.json();
        if (fetchData.status != 200) {
          reject("ERROR");
        } else {
          // get the token and save it in this.data
          this.data.accessToken = fetchData.access_token;
          this.data.expiresIn = fetchData.expires_in;
          this.data.tokenType = fetchData.token_type;
          resolve(fetchData);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }
  async isTokenValid() {
    if (new Date() >= this.data.expiresIn) {
      // Generate a new Token
      try {
        await this.getToken();
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
    // else - Do nothing and use current token saved in this.data.accessToken
  }
  async getData() {
    try {
      await this.isTokenValid();
      await fetch("url2 with this.data.accessToken");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}

let user = new StackClass("username", "password");

user.isTokenValid(); // SHOULD BE PRIVATE
user.getToken(); // SHOULD BE PRIVATE
user.getData(); // SHOULD BE PUBLIC
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance by "elsewhere" you mean somewhere outside of the class scope and then exporting them separately?

Comment: You don't want to export the 2 at all, right? You can define standalone functions defined only inside the module, and they won't be exported

Comment: @CertainPerformance That's correct, but If I drag those 2 out of the class and make them standalone, then they won't have access to properties of the class when a new instance of it is called and I need them to use an object which is created once the constructor is called

Comment: Pass the object to the function, and then have the function use, eg, `obj.prop` instead of `this.prop`?

Comment: the constructor will create that object and before the 'new class()' there simply is nothing to be passed and since my standalone functions are before creating the instance i'm gonna get undefined

Comment: It's really hard to figure out code that we can't see. Can you edit your question?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the `isTokenValid` and `getToken` as standalone functions instead. You should also avoid the explicit Promise construction antipattern, and only `catch` in a place where you can sensibly handle the error, which is usually in the *caller* of the asynchronous function (perhaps `getData`, perhaps in the consumer of the `StackClass` class):

```
class StackClass {
  constructor(p1, p2) {
    this.data = {
      p1,
      p2,
      accessToken: null,
      expiresIn: null,
      tokenType: null
    };
  }
  async getData() {
    try {
      await isTokenValid(this);
      await fetch("url2 with this.data.accessToken");
    } catch (err) {
      // or you can just avoid the `try`/`catch` altogether,
      // and have the consumer of getData handle problems
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}


function isTokenValid(stack) {
  if (new Date() >= stack.data.expiresIn) {
    // Generate a new Token
    return getToken(stack);
  }
  // else - Do nothing and use current token saved in this.data.accessToken
}
async function getToken(stack) {
  const fetchResponse = await fetch(
    "url with this.data.p1 and this.data.p2"
  );
  const fetchData = await fetchResponse.json();
  if (fetchData.status != 200) {
    throw new Error('error');
  } else {
    // get the token and save it in this.data
    stack.data.accessToken = fetchData.access_token;
    stack.data.expiresIn = fetchData.expires_in;
    stack.data.tokenType = fetchData.token_type;
  }
}
```

Comment: Silly me, was trying to use 'this' as a parameter in `function isTokenValid(this)` while passing it from await isTokenValid(this), thanks for both the tip about promises and this!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you export a function that takes a list of arguments, creates an object of your class with those arguments, and then return a new object literal with only *public* methods? Take a look:

**my-class.js**

```
class MyClass {

  constructor(f1, f2) {
    this.field1 = f1;
    this.field2 = f2;
  }
  m1() {

    this.m2();
  }
  m2() {

    console.log('this.field1', this.field1);
    this.m3();
  }
  m3() {
    console.log('this.field2', this.field2);
    this._m4();
  }

  _m4() {
    console.log('private m4');
    this._m5();
  }
  _m5() {
    console.log('private m5');
  }
}

module.exports = (f1, f2) => {

  const my = new MyClass(f1, f2);

  return {
    m1: my.m1.bind(my),
    m2: my.m2.bind(my),
    m3: my.m3.bind(my),
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
const myObj = require('./my-class')('f1', 'f2');

myObj.m1();
```

[Live demo](https://repl.it/repls/WebbedSeashellProducts)

This way you are hiding the *private* methods which should not be accessible outside of the module.

Comment: but it creates the instance inside of the module which if possible I want to avoid